# how to run .pl file on android mobile

Tags: android, perl

I want to run perl scripting files(which contains adb commands) on android moble.
Can any one suggest me how can we run perl file on android mobile.

If we can't directly run on phone,is there any way convert perl file to apk.

Comment: adb commands would normally run on your development machine, not on the device.

Comment: apk files are java, xml, resource etc files built into an executable the Android OS can understand.  I don't believe perl is allowed as one of the components.

I think the only way to do what you want is to find a tiny Perl installation and install it on your device first.  That strikes me like more trouble than its worth

Answer (score 5):

You can run Perl on an Android device using a combination of [Scripting Layer for Android (SL4A)](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) and [Perl for Android](http://code.google.com/p/perl-android-apk/).

But the `adb` (Android Debug Bridge) is a client-server tool for debugging Android applications by communicating with either an attached Android device or an emulator. Running it directly on an Android platform is meaningless.